# dijit.layout.ContentPane Image blinks at page load and disappears

Tags: dojo

I am using following code to show the picture. But image blinks at page load and disappears. Below is my php code.

```
echo "
                        <div data-dojo-type=\"dijit.layout.ContentPane\" class=\"dojoPane\" data-dojo-props=\"region: 'top'\" style=\"height: 25px; background-color: #EEEEEE;\"></div>

                        <div data-dojo-type=\"dijit.layout.ContentPane\" class=\"dojoPane\" data-dojo-props=\"region: 'center'\" style=\"overflow: hidden; padding: 0px;\">
                            <img src=\"$profilePhotoFile\" style=\"width: 100%;\">
                        </div>

                        <div data-dojo-type=\"dijit.layout.ContentPane\" class=\"dojoPane\" data-dojo-props=\"region: 'bottom'\" style=\"height: 25px; background-color: #EEEEEE;\"></div>
                    ";
```

Comment: It seems to work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/AP3Tu/embedded/
Find out if there are any errors in your browser console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, the problem is with CSS applied to the div containing above mentioned div. The CSS is not getting loaded, hence it is not displaying the dijit.layout.ContentPane